# Enable sticky button after scroll

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a sticky button in Wordpress (divi) with Id : buttonf

I want to enable it after scroll. So I add a jQuery code but it doesn't work, I tried many but don't understand why not.

```
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_40  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child"> 
    <div class="et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_button_0_wrapper et_pb_button_alignment_right et_pb_module ">
            <a id="buttonf" class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_0 buttonf et_pb_bg_layout_light" href="/#cool">Get Yours</a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery code :

```
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var btn = $('#buttonf');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
      btn.addClass('show');
    } else {
      btn.removeClass('show');
    }
  });

  btn.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, '300');
  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of code. Add your JS/HTML to the question. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There is only the html, please add the jquery code as well.